# Lookup and replace is not working in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update Found column value as 'Yes' in df dataframe, if Name is available in lookup dataframe. but below code is not replacing the value.

```
import pandas as pd
    
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ram','David','Roy','John','Ed'],
                 'Found':['No','No','No','No','No'],
                })
lookup=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Ram','Kate','John','Doll','Ed','Sins'],
                     'role':['App','App','App','App','App','App']})
df['Found'].replace(dict(zip(lookup.Name, 'Yes')),inplace=True)
```

my output-

```
Name       Found
0   Ram     No
1   David   No
2   Roy     No
3   John    No
4   Ed      No
```

What i need is -

```
   Name    Found
0   Ram     Yes
1   David   Yes
2   Roy     No
3   John    Yes
4   Ed      Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html),

```
df["Found"] = np.where(df["Name"].isin(lookup["Name"]), "Yes", "No")
```